# substitute of sum function

Tags: python-3.x, function, sum

I am new to Python and trying to solve a task while reading the content of a text file but getting the message: ''float' object is not iterable' when trying to sum all the outputs from the variable 'sppos'.All the outputs are numbers bigger than 0 of type 0.xxxx
Also trying to have the total of all values without using the sum function.
Any hints which other function could be used?

```
fname=input('Enter a file name:')
fhand=open(fname)
count=0
for line in fhand:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    count=count+1
    atpos=line.find(':')
    sppos=line[atpos+1:]
    sppos=float(sppos)
    print(count,sum(sppos))
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you put an example line from your file in your question please?  If you `print(sppos)` before you try to sum over it I think you'll find it's a single float instead of the list you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

The sum method needs an iterable as first parameter, thats it a list.

```
print(count,sum([sppos]))
```

If you want to get the total of spoos without the sum method just define a variable outside the loop and add spoos to it.

```
fname=input('Enter a file name:')
fhand=open(fname)
count=0
total=0
for line in fhand:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    count=count+1
    atpos=line.find(':')
    sppos=line[atpos+1:]
    sppos=float(sppos)
    total+=spoos
print(count,total)
```